# Users Export From Mysql Version 8.0 to 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7

I want to exports all users from mysql version 8.0 to 5.7. Can you guide me for this activity. I want same password and privs should migrate.

Comment: ``select `user`, `host`, `authentication_string` FROM `mysql`.`user`;`` will give all users. ``show grants for `username`@`host`;`` will give all grants for each user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed. I found mysql tables (db & user) columns available in 5.7. So i copy these tables from 8.0 to 5.7. And copy data only for available columns in tables db & user of mysql schema. Now its working fine.